# Forcing `mount` to bypass nfs kernel limitations in relation to the nfs version

Tags: nfs, mount, kernel, nfs4

According to this answer https://serverfault.com/a/1062570/253400 there's the possibility that the installed software supports nfs version `v4.2` but if the underlying kernel is not prepared, the `mount` command will then downgrade to a "known version by the kenrel" that could be `v4.0`.

According to the answer it seems that it's not a matter of the nfs libraries, but related to the `mount` command itself.

Is there any way to tell `mount` to "bypass" the mount "discovery" and tell it to bind the full capabilities of `v4.2` in the libraries regardless of the underlying kernel?

Comment: The kernel is the nfs client. An alternative is a user-space nfs client, like https://github.com/sahlberg/libnfs. But am not aware of any, that supports 4.2.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this serves the purpose of an answer. Clarifies a lot. Understanding that the kernel itself is the client helps me understand all. If you place your text as an answer I'll accept it and mark as "the" answer.

Comment: I have added some extra info to make it look as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is the nfs client, thus you are limited to it's capabilities.

An alternative is a user-space nfs client, like https://github.com/sahlberg/libnfs, with fuse, if you need a mounted files system. But am not aware of any, that supports 4.2.

Today it's easy to have host running a modern kernel and applications in a container, if a specific environment is required.